# Find probability that mean score of dice thrown 70 times is less then 3.3

Tags: statistics, sampling

**An unbiased dice is thrown once. Mean = 7/2, Variance = 35/12**

The same dice is thrown 70 times

1) Find the probability that the mean score is less than 3.3

2) Find the probability that the total score exceeds 260

Comment: Hint: the two parts of your question are very similar. The average score is less than $3.3$ exactly when the total score is less than $3.3 \cdot 70 = 231$. Likewise, the total score exceeds $260$ exactly when the average score exceeds $260/70$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (2), I suppose you are to use a normal approximation to the sum $T = \sum_{i=1}^{70} X_i,$ where $X_i$ is the number of spots showing at the $i$th roll.

You have
$\mu_T = E(T) = 70(7/2).$ Also, because rolls are independent $Var(T) = 70(35/12)$ and from that you can find $\sigma_T = SD(T).$

Then
$$P(T > 260) = P\left(\frac{T - \mu_T}{\sigma_T} > \frac{260 - \mu_T}{\sigma_T} \right) \approx 1- P\left(Z \le \frac{260 - \mu_T}{\sigma_T}  \right),$$
where $Z$ is standard normal.

(1) Similar, except that  $E(\bar X) = 7/2$ and $SD(\bar X) = \sqrt{(35/12)/70}.$